# как задать шрифт , когда код отвечающий за шрифт "не реагирует"

Tags: latex

Работаю в Latexe без gui, latex2rtf-2.3.1_win-NO-GUI . Но команда изменения шрифта не реагирует.

```
   \documentclass[14pt]{article}
```

Потом я попытался слегка изменить запрос

```
   \documentclass[14pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
   \documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{article}
```

После я решил переназначить команды

```
   \renewcommand{\tiny}{\fontsize{7}{8.4pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\fontsize{9}{11pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{11}{13.6pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand{\small}{\fontsize{12}{14.5pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{14}{18pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{17}{20pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand{\Large}{\fontsize{20}{25pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand{\LARGE}{\fontsize{25}{30pt}\selectfont}
```

Тоже переназначение но слегка по иному

```
   \renewcommand\tiny{\fontsize{7}{8.4pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand\scriptsize{\fontsize{9}{11pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand\footnotesize{\fontsize{11}{13.6pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand\small{\fontsize{12}{14.5pt}\selectfont}
   %\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{14}{16.8pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{14}{16.8pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand\large{\fontsize{17}{20pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand\Large{\fontsize{20}{25pt}\selectfont}
   \renewcommand\LARGE{\fontsize{25}{30pt}\selectfont}
```

но почему то не работают эти два варианта.

Не знаю что применить что бы шрифт 14 был вместо стандартного 10.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

перевод [ответа с другого сайта](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70384/79376):

класс документа `article` поддерживает только размеры `10pt`, `11pt` и 12pt (`10pt` — по умолчанию).

бо́льшие размеры основного шрифта вы можете получить с помощью `extsizes`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
```

пакет `geometry` (или `hyperref` или какой-нибудь графический драйвер типа `pdftex.def` или …) устанавливает размер бумаги для выходного носителя (output media).

Comment: Проблема в том что я работаю в  latex2rtf-2.3.1_win-NO-GUI и там нет такой библиотеки  (там библиотеки .tex) , в MiKTeX 2.9 это конечно работает но в latex2rtf-2.3.1_win-NO-GUI увы нет :_;

Comment: так добавьте нужную функциональность. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63367/79376